# Custom Post Type Category List & Post Count

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, count

I'm looking for Cutom Post Type Category List & Post Count. Here is my code..

```
            <?php
            $taxonomy = 'project-tags';
            $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
            ?>

            <?php
            foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
            echo '<li>' . '<a class="tag" href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '><span class="tag_name">' . $tax_term->name.'</span><span class="tag_count">'. $show_count. '</span></a></li>';
            }?>
```

This code works perfect for getting categories under my custom post type. But How do I get number of post count per category ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$tax_term->count` should contain the number of posts in the category. You may need to add the `$args` parameter if you want to include subcategory counts.

Docs: [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Answer (score 0):

or simply :

```
$args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => 'list',
    'show_count'         => 1,
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'feed'               => '',
    'feed_type'          => '',
    'feed_image'         => '',
    'exclude'            => '',
    'exclude_tree'       => '',
    'include'            => '',
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
    'show_option_none'   => __('No categories'),
    'number'             => null,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 0,
    'current_category'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'project-tags',
    'walker'             => null
); 

wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Comment: Please explain your code, rather than just pasting it into the answer box.