# list custom taxonomy with count

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users

I have a list of custom taxonomy and wish to add the number of posts in brackets, (9), after each listing.

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'judges';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all shows for %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a> </li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

I am using code shown on this thread **[Custom Post Type Category List & Post Count](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39094/custom-post-type-category-list-post-count)** and see that I should use $tax_term->count

Unfortunately, I don't have a clue how to use this.  I have tried inserting it into the code in different ways and places but I am obviously total ignorant!

Can anybody please advise me exactly where I place this and how to show the count in brackets?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'judges';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all shows for %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name . '(' . $tax_term->count . ')</a> </li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Try that?